# Multiple Facebook App ID for Single Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two Facebook App IDs - one for development and one for production. I already detect which environment I am in with my app, but for some reason, I can't seem to figure out how to switch between the development app id and the production app id.

When I log in to Facebook, I use this logic to set my Facebook App ID:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, callback, savedInstanceState);
    }
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(getActivity());
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        session = new Session.Builder(c).setApplicationId(c.getString(ENVRouter.getFacebookAppId())).build();
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
    }
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure this won't do anything because in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I *have* to include:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/dev_appId" />
```

This defeats the entire purpose of inserting `ENVRouter.getFacebookAppID()`. Is there a way I don't have to include that line in my application. Removing that line in `AndroidManifest.xml` yields an error:

```
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:281)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:266)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(UiLifecycleHelper.java:92)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.sapra.uevents.TestFragment.onCreate(TestFragment.java:47)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1481)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:838)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:843)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1071)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2259)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1388)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1587)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6567)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-20 21:12:22.981: E/AndroidRuntime(13919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
```

The line that the log says causes this is:

```
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.